# nivo slider, is a way to always show the next and prev arrows?

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

I am using nivo slider( default theme) and I positioned the prev and next arrows next to the image(not on top of the image) and I was wondering if there is a way to always show the next and prev arrows(right now the arrows only show when you hover over the image). Seems there should be a way to edit the code to do this but I can't seem to figure out where. Thanks!

Comment: I actually figured it out..... here's the solution if anyone needs to know how to do this ..... set directionNavHide:true to  directionNavHide:false , the code is located in the jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js file near the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open the nivoslider js file and find

{a(".nivo-directionNav",f).hide();f.hover(function(){a(".nivo-directionNav",f).show()},function(){a(".nivo-directionNav",f).hide()}

change to

{a(".nivo-directionNav",f).show();f.hover(function(){a(".nivo-directionNav",f).show()},function(){a(".nivo-directionNav",f).show()}

Save an upload.

Answer (score 11):

directionHideNav: false doesn't work as of 3.1.

Changes now need to be made in CSS
In the theme css file find the line

`.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a`

Change:
`opacity: 0;` to `opacity: 1;`

Comment: This is what you should do in the latest version (v3.1)

Answer (score 6):

Right way is;

just change or add directionNavHide value and set it to false in nivoSlider settings.

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({directionNavHide:false});
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy to do it without touching the JS code is just to add a line in your CSS file:

```
.nivoSlider .nivo-directionNav{
    display: block !important; /* ALWAYS show the arrows */
}
```

I'm not a big fan of !important, but if it means I don't have to adjust the js then it works for me.